# Circos plot with circlize

Tags: r, circos

This is the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42917349/r-circlize-circos-plot-how-to-plot-unconnected-areas-between-sectors-with-min/42996677) where they made circos using R I'm just following that the part answered by Zuguang Gu, not not sure what I'm doing wrong my [file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1UNkUO6numTeoLiBZlcl4kc7ah-roELWN), and the code:

```
library(ComplexHeatmap)
library(circlize)
 d11 <- read.csv("DC3_7_MUT.txt",stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
a <- as.data.frame(d11)
head(a)


ex <- melt(a, id.vars=c("Gene"))
head(ex)
dim(ex)

bb1 <- ex %>% na.omit() %>%
  group_by(Gene,value) %>% 
  mutate(new = n()) %>% 
  data.frame()

#head(bbb)
#dim(bbb)

bb1[bb1==""]<-NA

df <- na.omit(bb1)

bbb <- df

features1 = unique(bbb[[3]])
features_col1 = structure(rand_color(length(features1)), names = features1)

patients_col1 = structure(1:187, names = unique(bbb[[2]])) # I don't understand this



col1 = ifelse(bbb[[4]], features_col1[bbb[[3]]], "#FFFFFF00")
col1 = gsub("FF$", "80", col1) # half transparent
features_count1 = tapply(bbb[[4]], bbb[[3]], sum)
head(bbb)
# set color to white if it only exists in one patient/cell
col1[features_count1[bbb[[3]]] == 1] = "#FFFFFF00"
pdf("CIRCOS.pdf",20,25)
chordDiagram(bbb, col = col1, grid.col = c(features_col1, patients_col1))


dev.off()
```

The error

> chordDiagram(bbb, col = col1, grid.col = c(features_col1,
>   patients_col1)) Error in abs(df$value1[i]) :    non-numeric argument
>   to mathematical function

I'm doing something wrong but I'm not able to find out, secondly I didn't get the idea about the usage of structure the one I commented.

Am I using the right dimension for the structure argument?

A bit of progress with a bit of tweak in the code

```
d11 <- read.csv("DC3_7_MUT.txt",stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


blank2na <- function(x){ 
  z <- gsub("\\s+", "", x)  #make sure it's "" and not " " etc
  x[z==""] <- NA 
  return(x)
}

a1 <- data.frame(sapply(d11,  blank2na))

df <- a1
head(df)

df2 <- df[, colSums(is.na(df)) != nrow(df)]

head(df2)
dim(df2)



a <- as.data.frame(df2)
head(a)
ex <- melt(a, id.vars=c("Gene"))
head(ex)
dim(ex)
ex <- with(ex, table(paste(Gene,variable,sep='|'), value))
ex = as.data.frame(ex, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
head(ex)
ex <- ex[which(ex$value != ""),]
head(ex)
dim(ex)
ex <- (ex[which(ex$Freq == 1),])
head(ex)
dim(ex)


features = unique(ex[[2]])
features_col = structure(rand_color(length(features)), names = features)
patients_col = structure(1:280, names = unique(ex[[2]]))
col = ifelse(ex[[3]], features_col[ex[[2]]], "#FFFFFF00")
col = gsub("FF$", "80", col) # half transparent
features_count = tapply(ex[[3]], ex[[2]], sum)
# set color to white if it only exists in one patient/cell
col[features_count[ex[[2]]] == 1] = "red" 

#And the final chord diagram:

pdf("CIRCOS.pdf",20,25)

#png("circos.png",width =20,height=20,unit="cm",res=1000)
#chordDiagram(ex, col = col, grid.col = c(features_col, patients_col))

chordDiagram(ex, col = col, grid.col = patients_col, directional = 1,
             transparency = 0.25 , xmax = NULL,
             symmetric = FALSE, keep.diagonal = FALSE,
             direction.type = "diffHeight", diffHeight = convert_height(2, "mm"),
             reduce = 1e-5, self.link = 2,big.gap = 10,
             preAllocateTracks = NULL,
             annotationTrack = c("name", "grid", "axis"),
             annotationTrackHeight = convert_height(c(3, 2), "mm"),
             link.border = NA, link.lwd = par("lwd"), link.lty = par("lty"),
             link.sort = FALSE, link.decreasing = TRUE,scale = TRUE,
             link.arr.lwd = par("lwd"), link.arr.col = par("col"),
             link.largest.ontop = FALSE, link.visible = TRUE)


dev.off()
```

[image: this is somewhat im trying to but still not understandable]

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? What does each connection in the circos plot represent?

Comment: this i finally discarded ...